# Can we store a whole string with the help of a single character pointer? If yes , How?

Tags: c, string

> Here p is a character pointer not an array! Yet compiler gave no warning or error?

```
    char  *p = "Vladimir";
```

Comment: This is the wrong site for your question - read the text of your tag `c`. That said, your code is completely correct: read K&R.

Comment: @AFH Yeah that's what I'm asking why it is correct. Beacause pointer is a char pointer . So it must bot be able to hold the whole string !

Comment: This question is better suited to https://stackoverflow.com/

Comment: @Mawg okay I got it man

Comment: K&R is the standard definition of the C language by its designers, and your question is well explained there. I say again that you must read it.

Comment: @AFH Sure I'll give it a read.

Comment: You are question blocked on [so]. That doesn't mean you can ask your off-topic programming questions on [su]. See [On-Topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Please also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://superuser.com/help/dont-ask).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's only a matter of **interpretation**: `*p` is a character, you are right.

But the C routines from `string.h` or `stdio.h` will **interpret** `p` as pointer to the *first* character of a "string", with the following characters at consecutive addresses `p+1`, `p+2` and so on, and the convention that a zero character `'\0'` (which is added implicitly by the compiler!) will terminate the "string".

I use quotes for "string" here, because C (in opposite to C++) has no native string type at all.

C uses exactly this pointer-to-character for "strings". As a consequence, C "strings" cannot contain `'\0'` characters, and always use one `char` *more* space than visible at the first glance.

Comment: Please do not answer off-topic questions.

Answer (score 3):

The characters "Vladimar" are stored as a string literal, which is stored in the read-only segment of the executable image. The pointer is assigned to the **start address** of the string literal.

Note the compiler null-terminates string literals. String handling functions in C depend on the null terminator. When it is found, the function typically stops processing the string. So this works:

```
gets(p);
```

It is a quirk of C that the non-const pointer can be assigned to a read-only string literal (In C++, it is invalid to do so).

> A "string literal" is a sequence of characters from the source
>   character set enclosed in double quotation marks (" "). String
>   literals are used to represent a sequence of characters which, taken
>   together, form a null-terminated string.

Comment: Please do not answer off-topic questions.